# Hyphen in column name breaks function in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

My problem:

In a Wordpress site, I have a plugin which adds data to a table. The table has some columns whose names contain hyphens.

I don't know if this is exactly my problem but it seem that my function breaks when I try to  `echo` the content of that field.

My function code:

```
function members_display() {
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT text-529f61f42c30d AS name FROM wp_fm_data_5";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        echo $result->name;
    }
}
```

What i want to work is this:

```
function members_display() {
global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_fm_data_5";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result->[text-529f61f42c30d];
}
```

}

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Change  echo $result->[text-529f61f42c30d]; to echo $result->['text-529f61f42c30d'];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to surround the column name with  `. (Backtick)

```
$sql = "SELECT `text-529f61f42c30d` AS name FROM wp_fm_data_5";
```

Comment: Tried this. it displays: text-529f61f42c30d

Comment: Note that ` is not the same charavter as '